# excecute batch command over MSI Package

Tags: c#, batch-file, windows-installer, wmi

I have a huge network of PCs that are all in a same domain (active directory). I want to  enable **WMI service** and **relative port**, then set the domain's administrator credentials to **WMI credentials** over my entire network in the group policy.

For the Work Grouped network I created a batch file that does what I want but for the domain I want to do the best, execute the batch file remotely over entire network using active directory.

I know that the active directory lets me execute MSI Package.

The problem is: How can I create an MSI package that can be executed by a batch command?

something along the lines of...

```
@Netsh firewall set service RemoteAdmin enable
```

I would prefer to do this in C# .NET 4!

Comment: Are there any other options available to you? MSI doesn't seem like the best technology to use here. I'm wondering if the folks over at ServerFault might have some creative options to help...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't think that is the best method to do settings for your PCs.
But I say you how you can create the needed MSI.
Create the msi with needed batch files, and use custom action [type 34](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368092%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with Deferred and No Impersonate execution context.
Source for CA: the system32 folder (but not really matter)
Target for CA: `cmd.exe /c ""[INSTALLDIR]your-batch-file.bat"" arg1 arg2`

Include CA to `InstallExecuteSequence` between `InstallInitialize` and `InstallFinalize` phases.